# Interpolate between multiple lines

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Suppose I have the following 2 lines (the red and the blue the goes downwards in Y) lines and between them I have 5 parallel lines (blue lines):
[image]

I know the `(x,y)` of each point.

Now, I had like to interpolate simultaneously 5 lines instead of writing 5 times `interp1` as following:

```
y1 = interp1([0 9.858],[-2.132*10^-4 -5.691],xreq) 
y2 = interp1([2.912 10.8],[-8 -12.55],xreq2) 
y3 = interp1([5.824 11.74],[-16 -19.41],xreq3)
```

and so on.

Is there some elegant way of writing once `interp1` and inserting `x,y` as 2 column vectors or soemthing like this?

Edit: xref equals to quarter of the distance between the points so in each line of the 5 it will be slightly different value depends on the points at the edges (So xref is vector in length of 5).

Thank you.

Comment: Seems you can't call `interp1` only one time (unless the X coordinates are the same for each interpolation which is not the case). But you can construct your column vectors for the coordinates, and use a for loop instead of writing the call to the function 5 times

Comment: What is `xreq`? Is that one value? many values? Is it in between the two points? outside the two points?

Comment: @CrisLuengo What's the point of your question? Looks like we don't need to know `xreq` to answer the question

Comment: @CsuGouv: I am thinking of a method that avoids calling `interp1` altogether, but it depends on how `xreq` is defined.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Oh I see. But even in this case, with linear interpolation, all we need to do is finding the slope and the intercept, and multiply whatever is in `xreq` by slope and add intercept.

Comment: @CsuGouv: Yes, you can do that. You can also do `xreq=linspace(x0,x1,N); y=linspace(y0,y1,N);`. Ben: would that work for you?

Comment: @CrisLuengo it is nice, but you still need to call it 5 times. And all the points of `xreq` need to be in the range `(x0, x1)`

Comment: Have you considered `arrayfun`?  It is very handy and might work for something like this.